# How to use output of one network in a graph to feed to another network in another graph in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have a problem where I have two tensorflow graph networks
I'am feeding data into the first network and, manipulating the output of the network to create a new batch, I need to feed this new batch the second network in another graph in tensorflow, How to do it?

NOTE : The batch size of the two input data, i.e. the batch size of the first input data, and the batch size of the input data fed to the second network, are different.

Comment: Why do you require two different graphs? Can it not be done in single graph simultaneously?

Comment: so you use for example two batches of network 1 to build one batch in network 2? can you develop a little more on how these batch sizes interact? Most of the problems should be easy to solve using a reshape

Comment: @MNA I have tried to train the second network, when both network  in a single graph and the parameters of the first network fixed, but with lot of try I could not train the second network, and it always returns same value for each output of first network. So, that's why I was thinking may be it is the problem, that I am trying to train using both network in same graph, as batch size changes for two network.

Comment: @GabrielM no, I am implementing a faster rcnn model, where I feed an image to an rpn network, depending on the roi's predicted, I extract the feature values from the trained backbone, here the batch size changes depending on the prediction of rpn. This newly created batch is then fed to the next network to train it.